# Why do 3d charts appear to be labelled incorrectly

Tags: python, matplotlib, charts

The `ax.set_zlabel('Z')` appears to set the label on the y-axis. Am I being stupid or is something weird going on?

From the examples ([polygon plot](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html#polygon-plots)):

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib.collections import PolyCollection
from matplotlib.colors import colorConverter
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

cc = lambda arg: colorConverter.to_rgba(arg, alpha=0.6)

xs = np.arange(0, 10, 0.4)
verts = []
zs = [0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
for z in zs:
    ys = np.random.rand(len(xs))
    ys[0], ys[-1] = 0, 0
    verts.append(list(zip(xs, ys)))

poly = PolyCollection(verts, facecolors = [cc('r'), cc('g'), cc('b'),
                                           cc('y')])
poly.set_alpha(0.7)
ax.add_collection3d(poly, zs=zs, zdir='y')

ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_xlim3d(0, 10)
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_ylim3d(-1, 4)
ax.set_zlabel('Z')
ax.set_zlim3d(0, 1)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: The order of labelling is probably just convention.

Comment: Could that be related to `zdir='y'`?